# Use Circe to decode Normal Class (not case class)

Tags: scala, circe

I have written this code to read and write josn using circe

```
import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.parser._, io.circe.syntax._
case class Foo(i: Int)
val f = Foo(10)
val json = f.asJson.toString
val t1 = decode[Foo](json)
```

this works very well. But if I create a normal class Bar

```
class Bar { var i : Int = 0 }
decode[Bar](json)
```

Now I get error

```
 could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type io.circe.Decoder[$sess.cmd25.Bar]
```

So is it possible to work with normal classes and decode them from json using Circe?

Comment: Yes, it just cant auto-generate the decoder for you so you have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `io.circe.generic.auto._`, you're using Circe's automatic generic derivation, which is backed by Shapeless's `LabelledGeneric` typeclass. `LabelledGeneric` only works with product types like tuples and case classes. That's why your seeing this error, because Circe's auto mode could not automatically derive a Decoder instance for your plain class. What you can do is manually [implement](https://circe.github.io/circe/codec.html) a decoder for your class (see custom encoders/decoders part).

Answer (score 0):

Little addition to **LMeyer** answer.
If your `Bar` class quite simple, you can write `encoder` and `decoder` shortly using some `forProduct` functions:

```scala
import io.circe.{Codec, Decoder, Encoder}
import io.circe.parser._
import io.circe._

class Bar {
  val i: Int = 0
  val j: Option[String] = Some("value")

  override def toString: String =
    s"Bar(i: $i, j: $j)"
}

object Bar {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Bar] =
    Encoder.forProduct2[Bar, Int, Option[String]]("i", "j")(
    bar => (bar.i, bar.j)
  )
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Bar] =
    Decoder.forProduct2[Bar, Int, Option[String]]("i", "j")(
      (iValue, jValue) =>
        new Bar {
          override val i = iValue;
          override val j = jValue
        }
    )
  implicit val codec: Codec[Bar] =
    Codec.forProduct2[Bar, Int, Option[String]]("i", "j")(
      (iValue, jValue) =>
        new Bar {
          override val i = iValue;
          override val j = jValue
        }
    )(bar => (bar.i, bar.j))
}

val json =
  """{"i":42,"j":"Hello"}""".stripMargin

val bar = decode[Bar](json).getOrElse(throw new Exception("Decoding failed"))
// bar: Bar = Bar(i: 42, j: Some(Hello))
println(
  Printer.noSpaces
    .print(Encoder[Bar].apply(bar))
)
// {"i":42,"j":"Hello"}
println(
  Printer.noSpaces
    .print(Encoder[Bar].apply(bar)) == json
)
// true
```